# list items vertical gap IE

Tags: css, list

I've fixed almost 90% the gap, but I still see 2 px margin between list items.

```
.lines li {
border-bottom: solid #000 1px;
list-style: none;
background-color: #CF0;
height: 0px;
}

.lt-ie9 .lines li {
display: inline-block !important;
}

.lt-ie9 .lines li {
display: block !important;
background-color: #CC0;
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0px;
}


    <ul class="lines">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to inline-block display. You have to delete any space between your list items in your html code. You can replace it with commentary.

```
<p>Lorem Elsass ipsum</p><!-- whitespace
--><p>réchime amet sed bissame so libero knackes choucroute…</p>
```

See http://www.alsacreations.com/astuce/lire/1432-display-inline-block-espaces-indesirables.html if you can read french.

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for your post but I tried that already. (btw nice way to remove spaces using commentary while keeping the markup readable)